# Having a issue installing json

Tags: ruby, json

I have been trying and trying and I can't get past this error. I have Ruby version 1.8.7 and Gem version 2.1.11 and I am trying to install open project and I keep coming up with this error

Installing json (1.8.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Any help will be appreciated...

Best,

Mike

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
==> Something went wrong :(
==> Installation aborted.

Comment: Oh, and I am also using SUSE Enterprise.

Comment: You sure the gem you are trying to install is compatible with such an old version of ruby? Why don't you upgrade to 2.0?

Comment: that is a great idea. Let me try that now.

Comment: I tried updating Ruby and this is what I got..

Comment: rror running 'requirements_opensuse_libs_install libffi-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel',
showing last 15 lines of /root/rvm/log/1386501671_ruby-1.8.7-p371/package_install_libffi-devel_libopenssl-devel_readline-devel_zlib-devel.log (it won't let me install these packages) any ideas? This is a project for work. Getting frustrated with this now. :-)

Comment: It looks like there is still something with your old installation of Ruby, so why don't you try this: Setup RVM (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) and create an environment for you project that is running Ruby 2.0.0 by default. Then bundle install from there and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: I have RVM installed and here is what I get when trying to update..

Comment: rvm install 1.9.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: suse/11.1/i386/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Comment: Checking requirements for suse.
Installing requirements for suse.
Updating system......
Installing required custom packages: yaml............
Installing required packages: libffi-devel, libopenssl-devel, readline-devel, zlib-devel....

Comment: Error running 'requirements_opensuse_libs_install libffi-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel',
showing last 15 lines of /root/rvm/log/1386556100_ruby-1.9.2-p320/package_install_libffi-devel_libopenssl-devel_readline-devel_zlib-devel.log
[2013-12-08 21:28:29] requirements_opensuse_libs_install
requirements_opensuse_libs_install () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo zypper install -y "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /root
command(5): requirements_opensuse_libs_install libffi-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel
Refreshing service 'nu_novell_com'.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo gem install json` worked for me. Note: running `gem install json` did not work.